# Calculations of a sphere

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, mathematics, experimental-physics

I apologize if the question is very basic, I admit I'm not the best at math and physics.

I am doing an experiment with a sphere, the measurements are as follows:

- The sphere has a diameter of 330 mm (13 inches)
- D1 measures 75mm

I want D2 to be attached to D1 and both ends of D2 to be attached to the sphere. D1 must be attached to one end of the sphere. **I want to know how long D2 should be.** How can I do that calculation?

[image]

Update:
[image]

[image]

Comment: what are D1 and D2?

Comment: I know that a sphere has no end, obviously, but I am referring to one of the extremes, I don't know if I make myself understood. D2 is a tube that will be attached to the sphere "up" and "down", D1 is a box that measures 75mm. I want to know how long the tube (D2) should measure. D1 and D2 will go together. I want everything to be glued, that is, D1 is glued to one of the ends of the sphere and to D2... and D2 is glued to the sphere. **How big should the D2 be?**

Comment: So draw it, either full size or to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, consider a circle with same diameter as the sphere, with the distance $d_2$ being the projection of $D_2$ onto the plane and assuming $d_1=D_1$ relative to your figure:[image]
The radius of the circle is equal to the radius of the sphere, i.e. $r=165$mm.
We get a planar measure for $d_2$ that is
$$d_2=2\sqrt{r^2-(r-d_1)^2}$$
To get the length $D_2$ in 3D, we multiply $d_2$ by $\pi/2$
$$D_2=\pi\sqrt{r^2-(r-d_1)^2}$$

Comment: If you can explain it to me better, I will thank you from the bottom of my heart. If you help me with the answer I will also appreciate it, so I can practice with other numbers to see if I understood correctly.  (Many thanks for your explanation)

Comment: What is unclear ?

Comment: I get 434.46 mm

Comment: **sqrt(165^2-(165-75)^2)** = 138.29
**What am I doing wrong?** https://web2.0calc.es/ (copy and paste the formula that I placed **sqrt...**, so you can verify it quickly)

Comment: Please realize that the distance $d_2$ is not the same as $D_2$. My figure is in 2D but a sphere is in 3D. Multiply 138.29 by $\pi$ to get the same answer as me

Comment: I already understand the formula, but I think there is an error, there is something that does not add up. d2 is equal to 434.46 according to the formula, but it does not fit inside the sphere because the sphere has a diameter of 330. Can you clarify that for me, please?  138.29 seems more realistic to me, but you say no. I don't understand.

Comment: You said that the length $D_2$ is along the surface of a sphere. So $D_2$ is not the same as $d_2$, right ?

Comment: There is only 1 D2. D2 is a tube that will go in the top and bottom center of the sphere, as close to the left as possible.

Comment: See my update I uploaded a scaled image. It's also not 138.29.

Comment: According to the scale it is greater than 280 and less than 290. But I would like to have the exact formula.

Comment: If you are considering a circle, then $d_2=2\sqrt{r^2-(r-d_1)^2}=276.6$mm.
If you are considering a sphere, then $D_2=\pi\sqrt{r^2-(r-d_1)^2}=434.5$mm.
https://postimg.cc/nCJg7988

Comment: Where do you get 276.6 from? That formula gives me the same as before 138. **sqrt(165^2-(165-75)^2** https://web2.0calc.es/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136927/discussion-between-ronny-landsverk-and-principemestizo3).